# ESP8266 12E - How to use functions in SDKs

Tags: esp8266

This is kumar. I used the AT commands of ESP8266 12e successfully. It's AT version is 0.4 & SDK version is 1.3. but I don't how to use the functions that are given in its SDK. I want to interface ESP8266 12E to my cortex 32bit controller through SPI communication & also I want to use the Wi-Fi P2P functions which are given in the SDK. I'm using windows 10 OS & LPC controllers & KEIL IDE. so can anybody tell me what are the basic requirements that I need so that I can build my application program in my controller. since I'm new to SDK's or API's. In CC3000 Wi-Fi module, through SPI communication we can call its API functions through host controller. In the same way how can I call the SDK's function from my controller since they are stored in its flash(esp8266) & how can I know what are the functions available in SDK's & how to access them from controller. Since there is no proper document available for my question.

Answer (score 0):

You should start [here](http://bbs.espressif.com/viewforum.php?f=67) and read and understand the [Tutorial for Beginners.](http://bbs.espressif.com/viewtopic.php?f=67&t=821)